# Texturing a Toon Environment in Eevee: Height vs. Normal Map

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm working on a cel-shaded-esque environment in eevee. One of those environs where you plop down a 2d billboard to stand in for a person/creature. Anyway, I have a bunch of textures that are more suited for game-engine use (as they lack that realism that is sort of Blender-default). Those textures have fewer of the other textures I'm used to with PBR's.

I have a **Diffuse** map, a **Height** map and a **Normal** map. However, my experience so far is that Height maps seldom accompany Normal maps (at least in the many tuts I've followed and pages I've read).

Is this a use-one-or-the-other situation or should I be hooking the alpha of this thing into another of the grey plugs? I am pretty used to the basics of PBR's, but haven't really reasoned through the *Why* of some node setups. And not with regard to these non-realistic materials.

**More Follow-Up**

After further research, I am pretty sure that this Height map is meant to be used for the Displacement effect (to add height).

Here are the textures:
[image: My simple textures]

Here is a look at my nodes:
[image]

My hope is to use the appropriate map to create a smooth shape to my cobble. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

More Detail: I understand that EEVEE doesn't support the Bump & Displace setting. So I know I can't just easily do that via nodes. In another thread I found, it was recommended that I use Subdivision (which I have) and Displace, but in this case, with a repeating texture, I'm not sure that's doable.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If for some reason you need to use both the normal and the bump images, you can plug the Normal Map node into the Normal input of the Bump node, I don't know if that's what you're asking?

Comment: I guess I wasn't the most clear person.. I'm wondering, if I were to use both, how would I do it? Is that even wise?

Comment: as I say, for some reason you may have a situation where you have both: a normal image texture and a height (bump) image texture, in that case you can mix the two images so that they will be both taken account in the 3D appearance of your object, do you see how to organize the nodes (I can post picture if necessary)?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that you have "a Diffuse map, a Height map and a Normal map", did you create those maps? Or did you buy them? You may have been given normal and height to make sure that you have what you prefer, if they have the exact same effect, use only one

Comment: Bought 'em. I posted a pic of the textures above. So far I have a very basic node setup with the diff/color & normal map.

Comment: yes so your height image and your normal image look similar, you need to use either one or the other, depending on what result you'll prefer, there might be a small difference, just give it a test

Comment: Okay. Thanks very much!